# Can't figure out why NotificationListenerService isn't working

Tags: android

```
public class ReadNotifications extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        for (StatusBarNotification sbm : ReadNotifications.this.getActiveNotifications()) {
            String title = sbm.getNotification().extras.getString("android.title");
            String text = sbm.getNotification().extras.getString("android.text");
            String package_name = sbm.getPackageName();
            Log.v("Notification title is:", title);
            Log.v("Notification text is:", text);
            Log.v("Package Name is:", package_name);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<service android:name=".ReadNotifications"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Previously I was able to get NotificationListenerService to work, but now I can't figure out why it isn't working. I've tried running it as it is, trying to start the service from the main activity, creating notifications from the same app, sending notifications from another app, changing emulators, but no logs are being sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should grant the special permission in the android settings, you can open them like this (requires API level 22):

```
if (!NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(this).contains(getPackageName())) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS));
}
```

Comment: I added the extra condition @tofustore